# how to commit to a special branch in a bare repository with libgit2?

Tags: git, libgit2

I want implement a blog web app with history record feature based on Git. First, considering use `git init --bare` to save blog content.

But how could I do commit with a special branch?

I know, normally git shell command can't achieve commit operation to a bare repo if not checkout a branch to workspace.

Besides, github can edit and commit a file change to a specify branch if the repo is owned by yourself.

how about libgit2?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some struggle, I find libgit2 can create blob, tree and commit in buffer.

There are [sample code in GitHub](https://github.com/LoranceChen/libgit2-travel) but not document well yet.Hope it will be some help.